Unzipping .zip file on Mac (GUI vs. Command line)
I have a password-protected .zip file that I need to decrypt and unzip on a Mac.
If I go to the file in Finder, double-click on it, enter the password when prompted, it decrypts and unzips the file without issue.
However if I open terminal and try to unzip it using the following command line, it gives and error:
unzip targetfile.CSV.zip

Archive:  targetfile.CSV.zip
   skipping: targetfile.CSV  unsupported compression method 99

I understand that the error itself means that the compression algorithm isn't supported but something within the OS must be able to decrypt/unzip the file since it was able to handle it through the GUI (and, yes, I need to do it through the command line).
I probably will not be allowed to use a third-party tool like 7zip to unlock it.
How do I get the command line to decrypt/unzip the file?

Try ditto -x -k --password targetfile.CSV.zip ./

@Philippe - Unfortunately it gives the response, "Unknown Compression Type"

99 means that the entry is encrypted, not that it is using an unsupported compression method. The 99 hides the actual compression method, which is found elsewhere after decryption.
You can try the 7-zip command-line executable. That should be able to decrpyt and extract the zip file.
Alternatively you can create an AppleScript to do the action using Finder, and then make a command-line executable out of that using the osascript command.

I would prefer to use 7-Zip but since it seems to be getting blocked. I will look at learning AppleScript and see if I can launch that separately.  It seems like quite and lot and I still don't understand why the system can't simply perform the same steps to attempt to open the file through terminal that it does through Finder and the GUI (unless I am missing something).

It's simply that the command-line unzip utility does not support decryption. The Finder is using it's own code for unzipping, not unzip.

After going through some more research and looking through AppleScript, I noticed that the Open command is basically what I needed (e.g. - if the folder and file is "~/Documents/EncryptedFile.zip" then "Open ~/Documents/EncryptedFile.zip" prompts for the password, and it works just as in the GUI).

@J.C. You can also write your own answer here and accept it with the code that solved your problem, for others who search and find your question.
